# Jquery datepicker not setting 90days or 3months from the month selected in Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 dates `fromDate` and `ToDate` in which I want to implement a logic where if in

> FromDate is selected todays date, in ToDate the date should be active or enabled till previous 90 days or 3 months. Also max date in both textbox should be current date

Here is the code which I tried

```js
$(function() {
  $("#fromDate").datepicker({ //
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "+90y",
    defaultDate: null
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  
  $("#toDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: null,
    maxDate: 0,
    onSelect: function() {
      //$('#fromDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', $("#toDate").datepicker("getDate"));
    }
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input id="fromDate" type="text" value="16/02/2024">
<input id="toDate" type="text" value="16/02/2024">
```

Comment: @freedomn-m: this datepicker https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: ok, but that is not what the actual issue. I want to set it for 3 months max from the date of selection

Comment: @freedomn-m: ok, so how it can be done to set that user can select the date to previous 3 months date from current date ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the wording in the requirements and the attempted code:

> limit `from` date to be 90 days before `to` date when `to` date is changed

The attempt was very close, just need to subtract the days, eg using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/563442/2181514)

```
    onSelect: function() {
        let d = $("#toDate").datepicker("getDate");
      d.setDate(d.getDate() - 90);
      $('#fromDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', d);
    }
```

Updated snippet, using 3 days so it's easier to test:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#fromDate").datepicker({ //
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    maxDate: "+0",
    defaultDate: null
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
  
  $("#toDate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    defaultDate: null,
    maxDate: 0,
    onSelect: function() {
        let d = $("#toDate").datepicker("getDate");
      d.setDate(d.getDate() - 3);
      $('#fromDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', d);
    }
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input id="fromDate" type="text" value="16/02/2024">
<input id="toDate" type="text" value="16/02/2024">
```

Comment: yes its working for 3 days, how can I get it for 90 days ?

Comment: You could change the 3 to 90

Comment: I want to remove default date set on both the textbox how can I achieve it ?

Comment: ?? Remove `.datepicker("setDate", new Date())`?   It would be best if you knew what each line of code does when you write/copy it.